# Identifying weaker base

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

Can you tell me the reason behind the answer to this:

> Which is the weaker base?
>
> (**a**) *o*-cresol; (**b**) Trifluoro-*o*-cresol.

Answer: (**b**) trifluoro-*o*-cresol.

I'm not a student in any institution. So it's not homework and it was in the chapter reaction mechanism. I'm studying for a medical exam. So basically I'm on my own. Just found this in an old book, but it offered no hints.

Is it the hydrogen bonding between H and F? That's my best guess, because I think it's a case of ortho effect exception. In ortho effect it doesn't matter which group comes at *o*-position. The basicity decreases regardless of the group. But if memory serves me right, I think my teacher said there were some exceptions. So that's my best guess.

Comment: The weaker base is the stronger acid. The electron withdrawing effect of the 3 F atoms makes the phenoxide of tri-F- cresol more stable so it is more acidic than cresol.

Comment: The stronger acid has the weaker conjugate base. If the (deprotonated) conjugate base is more stable, it is easier for the (protonated) acid to donate a proton.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the order of acidic strength and reverse it to find basic strength as a weaker base will be stronger acid and vice versa. Among them trifluoro-*o*-cresol is more acidic because after the removal of acidic hydrogen the negative charge thus generated is stabilized by the *−I* effect of three fluorine atoms.
Whereas in the former the $\ce{CH3}$ molecule provides *+I* effect which destabilizes the negative charge. So, trifluoro-*o*-cresol which is a more stronger acid is thus the weaker base among them.